# Prior to the start of the project = When the project begins?

Tags: ielts

Prior to the start of the project = When the project begins?
In True/False/Not given question of Ielts, it is said that these two phrases are equivalent, but I think 'Prior' takes place before and 'when' takes place at exact starting point. Please explain if I am correct.

Comment: You are correct: the two phrases are not equivalent. But they *could* be interchangeable in *some* contexts.

Comment: More context would be needed to accurately assess this, as neither phrase can stand on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to the start of the project = *Before* the project 1 begins/2 began

1 Prior to the start of the project, I will ask my boss for more funding

2 Prior  to the start of the project, I (had) asked my boss for more funding